# Query SQL Update from select

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How to update this column **rank** with a SQL query?

```
char_id|char_name|point|w_point|rank|
-------|---------|-----|-------|----|
 100000|Adminn   |   17|     17|   0|
 100008|admin3   |    2|      2|   0|
```

with select

```
SELECT 
    char_id, 
    char_name, 
    `point`,
    `w_point`,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY `point` DESC) as `rank`
FROM 
    glro_worlddrop;
```

The result I want in column **rank** update

```
char_id|char_name|point|w_point|rank|
-------|---------|-----|-------|----|
 100000|Adminn   |   17|     17|   1|
 100008|admin3   |    2|      2|   2|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `char_id` is unique, use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE glro_worlddrop w JOIN
       (SELECT w.*,
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY `point` DESC) as new_rank
        FROM glro_worlddrop w
       ) ww
       USING (char_id)
    SET w.rank = ww.new_rank;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer yes `char_id` is unique still fail

Comment: @YoonJunho . . . What do you mean "still fail"?

Comment: ```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RANK() OVER (ORDER BY `point` DESC) as new_rank
        FROM glro_worlddrop w
' at line 3``` im using MariaDB 10.3.-15 under xampp

Comment: sorry i just wake up, thanks man for the revision missing (comma) after `w.*` work great!!